# React- cannot read property 'isvalid' of undefined in react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have been trying to disable the button  with multiple inputs using react hook form.

I have used the mode : 'onchange'

But it is throwing error like Typerror - cannot read properties isValid of undefined.

Comment: can you post a bit of your code ?

Comment: Hey Sarada! Welcome to stackoverflow!
When posting a question make sure to include a minimal, reproducible example.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.